# In Javascript is checking for the type only using typeof operator bad?

Tags: javascript, types, typeof

I see there are a whole lot of different ways to check the typeof a var in Javascript.

But using the typeof of operator seems pretty simpler than other ways -
e.g.

```
if(typeof someVar == typeof "")

if(typeof someVar == typeof [])


function myFunc() {}

if(typeof someVar == typeof myFunc)
```

Is it even valid or a really bad practice to do that? Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof` is perfectly fine to use, but not for general type checking. That's not its purpose.

```
typeof [] == "object"
```

It can only distinguish between `"object"`, `"function"`, `"undefined"` and the primitives `"boolean"`, `"number"` and `"string"`. For more advance type checking, you need to use `instanceof` or more complicated checks.

```
[] instanceof Array // works reliably only if there's a single frame
toString.call([]) == "[object Array]" // always works, but only with some types.
```

Comment: The `instanceof Array` test will not work if you have multiple window objects (such as in i/frames). That is `window.frames[0].Array == That is window.frames[1].Array` returns false

Comment: @JuanMendes: Oops! I meant to say that, but seem to have let a few words slip out of my post. Editing.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main problems of typeof, is that it won't return "string", "boolean", "number" if you create those objects using their constructors. Look at this example testing for strings

```
typeof "my-string" // "string"
typeof String('my-string') // 'string'
typeof new String("my-string") // "object".
```

Therefore, when testing whether an argument or variable is a string, boolean, number, you need to use Object.prototype.toString which returns consistent results

```
function isString(obj) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == "[object String]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if both the values and types are the same you can use the `===` comparison operator; however, if you just need to check the type it would be most appropriate to use `instanceof`.

Comment: While I agree with you, this does not mean that everything on w3schools is inaccurate. It can be a useful resource, just as StackOverflow is.

Comment: Most web developers disagree with you Norman, may be there is some accurate information there, but why would you keep referring to a website where their descriptions are sloppy and examples perpetuate bad coding style.

Comment: touche. I don't use it, and is the first time I've referred to it, but will be sure to refer to better resources in the future :)